# Azure Logic App Request Trigger authorization

Tags: azure, authentication, azure-logic-apps

I have a Logic App with an HTTP initial trigger that is all set up:

[image]

When I make the POST to the URL that is given to me (looks like `https://___.azure.com/workflows/___/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?____`), I get back:

```
{"error": {
   "code":"AuthorizationFailed",
   "message":"The authentication credentials are not valid."
}}
```

For this case, I need to accept anonymous calls.

Where in the Azure Portal do I setup the permissions for this?

The closest I've found is the "Access Control Configuration", and it is set like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Logic Apps does not allow anonymous calls, you are required to provide the SAS key, which is provided in Url generated on the request card.

Comment: So, if the call uses the URL generated on the request card, it should work?  That's the URL I'm using, and it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. My client-side code was appending a parameter to the URL without realizing the URL already had query parameters. As such, it was adding to the last parameter rather than adding a new parameter. With that fixed, the call works.

Comment: This is the exact issue with mine too. Thanks for updating with answer, please mark it as answered

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the URL that will be present at the callbacK URL while creating should work, Does your URL has SP, sv and sig query paramemters?

Comment: Yes, here is the (redacted) URL:

https : //___.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/___/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-06-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=___

Comment: is the Logic app running when you hit the run button on top of the logic app and also how are you calling this logic app?
The way calling should not matter as long as we are using the SAS URL to make the call with out any updates to it.